# Return IAsyncEnumerable<T> how to set the MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit on controller level

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I am implementing buffering on .net core 3.1, so i am returning

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{

}
```

I am setting the `MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit` on 
`.AddControllers(options => options.MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit = 'N')`

So this will be applied to all controllers. Is there anyway to set `MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit` on individual controller level, because I want to implement buffering only on select few controllers

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is unfortunately **no**, you cannot set it at the controller-level.

A search of the aspnet.core github for `IAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit` brings us to the `AsyncEnumerableReader` class. You can see on [line 88](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/58cf2304a642312477dc41cd9651e6f4c2d39286/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/AsyncEnumerableReader.cs#L88) that the reader only looks at the single property on the `MvcOptions`:

```
if (count++ >= _mvcOptions.MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit)
{
      throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.FormatObjectResultExecutor_MaxEnumerationExceeded(
                        nameof(AsyncEnumerableReader),
                        value.GetType()));
}
```

The `ObjectResultExecutor` class uses the `AsyncEnumerableReader`class under the hood when it detects an async enumerable. It passes no other options than the default `MvcOptions` when it [constructs the instance](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/58cf2304a642312477dc41cd9651e6f4c2d39286/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs#L72):

```
_asyncEnumerableReaderFactory = new AsyncEnumerableReader(options);
```